# Create Northwind.mdf for use in local db

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

The following is the start if the standard Install Northwind sql script as provided by Microsoft in their Install sql server 200 sample databases.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

USE master
GO
if exists (select * from sysdatabases where name='Northwind')
        drop database Northwind
go

DECLARE @device_directory NVARCHAR(520)
SELECT @device_directory = SUBSTRING(filename, 1, CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf', LOWER(filename)) - 1)
FROM master.dbo.sysaltfiles WHERE dbid = 1 AND fileid = 1

EXECUTE (N'CREATE DATABASE Northwind
  ON PRIMARY (NAME = N''Northwind'', FILENAME = N''' + @device_directory + N'northwnd.mdf'')
  LOG ON (NAME = N''Northwind_log'',  FILENAME = N''' + @device_directory + N'northwnd.ldf'')')
go

exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','trunc. log on chkpt.','true'
exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','select into/bulkcopy','true'
GO

set quoted_identifier on
GO
```

Under normal circumstances I always use a full copy of sql server or sql server express for development, however an unrelated support issue with a third party component has occurred that requires me to provide a self contained sample application with the basic nortwind database file contained within the sample using localdb.

To that end how should I adapt the Execute Create Database section of the sql script so that it will create a copy of the nortwind .mdf in a given location (let's say C:\MyData  so that I can then use, that file to send with the sample I need to build for the support team.  Essentially it is vital that they have a completely self contained sample to help narrow down the problem.

Many Thanks

Comment: Why don't you detach your northwind database from your sqlserver instance, grab a copy of the MDF/LDF files and use them for your LocalDB connection string?

Comment: Currently I have sql server 2014 on my system and the current mdf file for northwind appears not to be backwardly compatible with the local db that shipped with vs 2012 in which I need to supply the solution

Comment: I think that your best option (and probably the only one) is to find a Sql Server 2012 (also an Express) instance then. Let see if someone has a better idea.

Comment: I think you're right.  It shouldn't be too difficult to fire up a 2012 copy of sql express on a different machine and create what's required there.  Typically I'm just trying to be a little lazy.  Never seems to work that way when you want it to though!

Comment: This is one of the reasons why a clean virtual machine should always be ready to start.